# Array and For loop for in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, for-loop

I am having two variables as below

```
$IP=@("IP1","IP2","IP3")
$Hostname=@("Host1","Host2","Host3")
```

I am working on some project in which there is Combobox and if the user selected the first choice then there is some command which should take variable as first IP and first hostname and when user select "ALL-DC" option, the command should be running on every IP and hostname one by one.

I am using below code

```
if ($Unity_ComboBox.text -match 'unit-02') {
$Unity=$IP[0]
$show=$hostname[0]
} elseif ($Unity_ComboBox.text -match 'zone-03'){
$Unity=$IP[1]
$show=$hostname[1]
} elseif ($Unity_ComboBox.text -match 'site-04'){
$Unity=$IP[2]
$show=$hostname[2]
} elseif ($Unity_ComboBox.text -match 'ALL DC'){
 $Unity=$IP
 $show=$hostname
}

foreach ($u in $Unity){

echo $u
echo $show

}
```

In individual its working fine but in case of ALL DC it's messing up with $show.
Could someone suggest me some better way to achieve this?

Comment: You really need to gen up a sample form to show what you are doing, because as posted, this is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner using a better regex:

```
if($Unity_ComboBox.text-match".*DC-0([2-4]).*"){$Unity=$IP[$matches[1]-2];$show=$Hostname[$matches[1]-2]}elseif($Unity_ComboBox.text-match"ALL DC"){$Unity=$IP;$show=$Hostname}
```

- Here the first regex is `.*DC-0([2-4]).*` capture the last computer index. If your form takes only the names nothing more then change it to `^DC-0([2-4])$`.
- Then assign two variables using the match.
- If not, do the else

Comment: i have included only three in question but actually there are multiple text with different names.  I am looking some thing like foreach ($u in $unity) -and ($k in $show)

Comment: Then you can modify the regex last part `[2-4]` to `[start-stop]`

Comment: I have edited my question with different texts. My main need is of the variation in for loop so that we can get the individual values of hostname and Ip and when ALL DC selectd then all values of IP and hostname one by one in loop.

Comment: Then use regex `^.*-0([2-4])$`

Comment: @wasif-Bro this helping me in reducing my if-else code but my main purpose is not yet solved. I want when a person selects ALL DC, I could use it in for loop for my command which required individual value of IP and hostname. like example write-host "This is my  $show, this is my hostname $u"

Comment: for ($i=0; $i -lt $IP.Count; $i++ )
{
    write-host "This is my $($IP[$i]), this is my $($hostname[$i])"
}

This code is great when there ll be ALLDC but then what for the individual entries.